# Which file contains info about the header logo?

Tags: magento-community, magento-1.9

Magento is not displaying the header logo no matter what theme I'm using.

I might have commented out or deleted the section in the file, but I forgot and I got lost several times figuring out where it might be in the many sub folders of Magento.

I'm aware that the header info usually is stored in a header.php file and in Magentos case a .phtml file

Maybe I turned off the display inside Magento backend.

I'm new to Magento so I've been lost a few times in the back end.

Can someone please tell me how to bring it back on?

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: Welcome to Magento! Please check this [great debugging tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429) and report back.

Answer (score 3):

The logo is rendered by `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml`.
The image for the logo can be set from `System->Configuration->Design->Header->Logo Image Src`.
The path you put there must be relative to `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turned out that i had written image/img.png instead of images/img.png in the config - design in Magento. Again thank you both for helping me. It was a big help :)

Comment: @user9967. If one of the answers solve your problem, mark it as accepted. Don't leave loose ends.

Answer (score 0):

1.Save image at the below location

> /magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images/

2.Go to admin section

> System >Configuration >General > Design > Header > Logo Image Src

put the location as `images/image name`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turned out that i had written image/img.png instead of images/img.png in the config - design in Magento. Again thank you both for helping me. It was a big help :)