# i want to change the logo on my site. i have tried every method

Tags: admin

i want to change the logo on my site. i have tried every method available.
i have uploaded my new logo to skin/frontend/default/default/images/
over and over again.
i have flush my magento cache, clear my browser cache as well. i am not a big magento guru so someone should please help me.i installed a quickstart for a magento theme and i can change the logo to mine. so i need help please.

Comment: If you right-click on the logo that Magento displays now and select "Copy image location". Paste it here.

Comment: there is nothing like copy image location there. instead its link location. and thats the link to my homepage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which file contains info about the header logo?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/which-file-contains-info-about-the-header-logo)

Answer (score 1):

The logo can be changed in the admin backend:
System > Configuration > Design > Header Section > Logo Image Src option

The path entered is relative to `skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme`/ directory.

Comment: i have done that but its still not changing. i have even deleted the old logo. its still the same story. jcjewel.com thats the link to my page. i have just installed the quickstart of the theme i want to use

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way is to login to your admin, go to `system >> configuration >> Design`

1. Check your package and theme name for the desired configuration scope.
2. Open the Header Tab from the same page, check the Logo image src, like images/logo.png
3. Upload the image to the path `/skin/frontend/package name from point 1 /theme name from point 1 / Logo image src from point 2`.

Note that if the name of your logo is different from the one saved on point 2, either update the name in configurations and save OR use your logo name and file extension same as in configurations.

Comment: public_html/skin/frontend/default/jm_megamall/images

Comment: i have uploaded it here again and also in the configuration on my admin panel i have set it like this images/logo.png. as it stands the logo is uploaded here       public_html/skin/frontend/default/default/images        and here public_html/skin/frontend/default/jm_megamall/images.... i have clear cache. i even deleted the old logo. please i dont know what to do again

Comment: If you installed the sample data, then you're watching the English store and it may just be overridden at the website level. In System > Configuration, change the slider in the upper left corner. At each "scope" you can select, check the settings. Also, the value for the path in the admin should *not* include `public_html/skin/frontend/default/jm_megamal`.

Comment: jcjewel.com thats the page. i have done all you suggested. still the same problem. it is not removing the logo for the quickstart of the theme i used.

Comment: please break it down from the start can i get a step by step guide on how to do it ? maybe i am not doing something right

Comment: this is after visiting your site, your package is `default` while the theme is `jm_megamall`, do you see that in the configurations as mentioned in step 1?